# what's the difference between create and create! in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

for seeding some data using Active Record, I am using `Product.create ***:***, ***,***`

I found it can successfully seed the data into the table.

Someone told me I should use `Product.create! ***:***, ***,***` is there any difference? Why I should use create!? Is this a must?

Comment: Did you check the documentation ?

Comment: Both are same `Product.create!` method works like the `Product.create` method, except that it raises an ActiveRecord::Record-Invalid exception if the creation fails."

Comment: You should use `create!` when you need its behavior. If you don't, you should use `create`. As simple as this.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is how failed saves are handled. When updating an ActiveRecord class the `!` version will raise an exception if the record is invalid.

Comment: How did you manage to answer closed question?

Comment: It might be, I just made a answer before your duplication OR I had already opened the page for answer after that you made duplicate,

Comment: :), OR it can be stackoverflow bug

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252711/this-answer-was-posted-after-the-question-was-closed-how-is-that-possible

Ok, I have my explanation. :)